# MVVM - Who is responsible for

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

I'm a little bit confused at the moment because I'm not sure about things like "who is responsible for validating model data".

To give it an example:

I've got an application in which a relationship between a Person and specific devices gets visualized.

```
public class Person{
    public string Firstname {get; set;}
    public string Lastname {get; set;}
    public SomeSortOfDevice SomeSortOfDevice {get; set;}
}

public class SomeSortOfDevice{
    public DateTime DeviceExpiration {get; set;}
    public string DeviceSerialCode {get; set;}
    //public bool IsSerialCodeValid{get{
    //     SomeValidationLogic()
    //}
}
```

In the View the App-User can change the data of the Device.
Now there are some Rules - for example the DeviceExpiration is bound to a TextBox but should only be Enabled if a valid SerialCode is set.

But who decides if the SerialCode is valid? The model itself? The ViewModel? Should the Model hold an extra Property "IsSerialValid" or how could the IsEnabled Property of a TextBox be bound to that rule?

**Edit 1**

```
public class ViewModel{
    public Person SelectedPerson {get; set;}
}
```

Thats how I'd use the Models above - The View will get some bindings on the SeletedPerson.

**Edit 2**

I think it's a litte bit more complicaten than I explained it before. Let's assume the Device is a Token and I want to determine if the User has entered something - if he entered something, is it valid?

If the validation should be handled in Model (as I've got it at the moment) the Model would look like this:

```
public Token{
    public DateTime ExpirationDate {get; set;}
    public string Serial {get; set;}
    public bool IsTokenExpired{
        get{
            return ExpirationDate.Date < DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
    public bool IsTokenValid{
        get{
            return new Regex("[0-9]{8,12}").Match().Success;
        }
    }
    public bool IsTokenSet{
        get{
            return TokenSerial.Length > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Now to Enable the TextBox where the User should Enter (or select) a Date the Binding looks like this:

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedPerson.Token.IsTokenValid}"/>
```

This works just fine but I don't really have got a good feeling about the validation rules inside the Model.

Comment: The `ViewModel` should handle the validations

Comment: Could you show us the Command that you want to execute if the validations pass?

Comment: Look into IDataErrorInfo, WPF controls support it.

Comment: I've heard about IDataErrorInfo but I don't want to notify the user about an invalid state of the serial - I just want to disable another control.

Comment: Then we're not talking about validation as such but about UI logic, a task for the VM.

Comment: Why aren't you happy with validating in the Model? In this case, i think it's the place to do it. Other thing is, if for example, you want to validate a Date to be valid. In that case, i'd probably do it in the ViewModel or even in the View..

Comment: The main question is - should a Model hold Properties for Validation (e.g. IsTokenValid) OR should the View itself should determine if something's valid (IsEnabled = {Binding SelectedPerson.Token, Converter=TokenIsValidConverter}) OR even with a Validator as @HenkHolterman mentioned.

Comment: No, I don't think the model should hold any property as `IsTokenValid`, but it should hold the Validating method, as `ValidateToken(string token);`The property should be in the ViewModel as in my answer.

Comment: @Pikoh - now I got it - i interpreted your answer wrong. But is this the "best practice" even if I've got the in the question mentioned "10 Textboxes" ?

Comment: Ok, if you had 10 TextBoxes and one Button, what i'd probably do is have one bool property binded to the Button enabled (or better, checking that property in a Command CanExecute method) and in the setters of all 10 TB call a validating method which will check all of them, and only set the property to true if all validate. I hope you understand me, because i wouldn't :)

Comment: @Pikoh no, I totally understand - there would be one Method which evaluates and set a Property to true only if all TB's pass. That's a good point but I've to admit that I always want to simplify my question - and because of that most of the answers will not fully fit :) - In my App there are TB's that depend on other TB's - so TextBox 5 shold only be enabled if TextBox 2 has a (valid) value - the other ones may or may not depend on others. It's a little bit complicated. But at the moment I think it would be best practice if I'll implement an "IsSet" Property for each TB' in my VM, wouldn't it?

Comment: Well, of course all this depends a lot on each case, and without having the whole picture is difficult to say. But yes, in your case I think you should have a property for each textbox,as some of them depends on the others :)

Comment: Shouldn't the validation logic be managed by your control? Create a SerialCodeTextBox instead of using plain TextBox and provide the validator for the control by a resource.

Comment: So this is a matter of opinion - At the moment I've got a TextInputControl (UserControl) which itself got an IsSet property - kinda like the SerialCodeTextBox you mentioned, @JanneMatikainen. Now I'm more confused of what I should use - Controls for everty use-case or additional Properties inside my ViewModel.

Comment: IMO the validation logic is not viewmodel logic, nor control logic. It is just validation logic and should be contained in a SerialCodeValidator instance which implements IValidator interface. So make an control that will use the IValidator implementation provided by a resource / binding. This way your control will be more versatile and supports multiple use cases.

Comment: I never heared about the IValidator Interface - could someone give me an example on how (and where) to use it?

Comment: That would be just something you define and then use within your application development framework.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is just an opinion,but this is how i would do it.

First, your model should have a validation method, something like `public bool ValidateSerial(string serial);`

Then, in your ViewModel you'll have a property binded to the TextBox and you'll do the check there,something like:

```
_private string _serialNumber;
public string SerialNumber
{
    get
    {
         return this._serialNumber;
    }
    set
    {
         this._serialNumber=value;
         RaisePropertyChanged("SerialNumber");
         this.IsSerialValid=Model.ValidateSerial(string serial);
         RaisePropertyChanged("IsSerialValid");
    }
    public bool IsSerialValid { get; set;}
}
```

The `IsSerialValid` property is the one you'll bind to the `IsEnabled` property of the other TextBox.

Hope this make sense to you.

Comment: This looks a lot like the solution I've got at the momen - as mentioned in my edit I'm no really happy with this

Comment: I noticed that in this case SerialNumber would be a Property of your ViewModel - why would I do that if SerialNuber is already contained inside my Model?

Comment: Because in the Model won't be a property, but a validating method. I've changed the name as it was confusing @Chill-X

Answer (score 1):

I think it all depends on the specific design. In general, you can implement some logic checks in the model, but the model should not (and cannot) communicate with UI. So typically the model would just refuse to store the data if something is wrong.

The visibility of controls should be handled in ViewModel, as you correctly suggested in your code. However, in your case when someone enters incorrect serial code, the IsValid property would not be changed (since in is calculated on demand). The better way would be to check the Serial Code in the setter of DeviceSerialCode, and set the IsSerialCodeValid from there. In order for the UI to reflect the change, your ViewModel should also implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface, and signal changes to the properties in their setters.

Comment: When you say the model should not communicate with the view - does that mean it's not correct to reference e.g. SelectedPerson.Firstname (as SelectedPerson is of Type Person (Model)) but instead implement an extra firstname property in the viewmodel itself? Seems like this would result in a mess...

Comment: I think it's okay to reference model objects in data bindings, but in general you should not create extra fields in the model that will reflect some UI properties (eg. visibility of elements, etc.). Model should reflect the problem domain, and viewmodel should handle all the view logic.

Answer (score 0):

No need to hold an extra property. Just implement the interface INotifyPropertyChanged which emits an event when the property value changes.

You can listen to the property's property changed event in the view model and do the checking there. This is how the view also gets updated in an MVVM model.

You can also bind the textbox's IsEnabled property to a viewmodel property which is set during the check if it contains a valid value.

If you want, you can also use a converter for the IsEnabled property and pass the text as Command Parameter, so that the converter checks the text and sets the bool value of IsEnabled property of textbox as required.

Comment: That's the question - is it a Validation or Conversation if I want to validate an input and represent it as a bool value. Lets assume I've got 10 TextBoxes and one Button on my View - the button should be enabled if all TB's hold a valid file path  - should my ViewModel handle 10 additional properties "IsFileOneValid" etc. to "notify" the other controls on the view about the validation status?

Comment: No you can manage it using a single property. You can listen to the property's or class's property changed event and do the checking when the event occurs and set a boolean value to true or false.

This bool property is bound by the button's IsEnabled property. So even if one text box is invalid, the property will be false and the button will be inactive.